# How do I program a model I downloaded, in python to show up when I run the program?

Tags: python, graphics, 3d, pycharm, pyopengl

Ok, so I downloaded an airplane I like here: https://www.turbosquid.com/3d-models/free-raytheon-a36-bonanza-aircraft-3d-model/310334

How do I program it in pycharm to where I can view it and then later program it?

Comment: This seems to be a variation of the question you asked earlier, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53495462/how-do-i-import-obj-models-in-pycharm-using-pyopengl

Comment: I know but I'm not getting any answers. The link  pygame.org/wiki/OBJFileLoader  I don't know how to use that. It doesn't work. I need a step-by-step guide on how to do this. :(